# Composer out of memory - need alternative way to increase PHP memory_limit

Tags: php, magento, composer-php

I'm trying to install an extension on a client's Magento 2 via Composer, but I'm running into the old PHP out of memory error.

My client is hosted with Bluehost, which unfortunately means I can't just go in and change the memory_limit in php.ini, as it's read only, and their cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor doesn't affect SSH. My client has been in touch with Bluehost, and they were told Bluehost doesn't allow SSH memory_limit to be altered, HOWEVER, my client only recently had to install a different extension, which required the memory_limit to be increased, but they did it themselves and they can't remember what commands they used or the file they edited.

I can confirm Composer is installed properly on the server, since I can run the command `composer require path/to/extension`. This just results in the out of memory error.

Running the command `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require amasty/advanced-review` results in the same error:

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 809508864) (tried to allocate 4096
bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer
/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 126
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to get things working properly?

Comment: Do have user.ini files enabled? Then you could create a new .ini just like the `.htaccess` and override it. In general `memory_limit` is `PHP_INI_ALL` which mean you can set it anywhere (`.ini`, `ini_set` and `.htacess`).

Comment: @CodeSpirit, sorry, I wasn't clear. I tried all that, but the way Bluehost is set up prevents the memory limit from being overridden except via cPanel's MultiPHP INI Editor. The good news is, Peter solved my problem, which was actually not what I thought it was!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't running into the PHP memory limit. If that where the case the error message would be something like "Allowed memory size of N bytes exhausted". The failing [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) call suggests that you are running out of physical memory.

Either upgrade the host or do the dependency updates on another machine with more memory. To do so

1. Copy composer.json and composer.lock to a machine with sufficient memory
2. Run `composer require amasty/advanced-review --no-scripts --ignore-platform-reqs` on that machine
3. Copy the updated composer.json and composer.lock files back to the Bluehost machine
4. Run `composer install` on the Bluehost machine

This works because `composer install` doesn't do any complex dependency resolution and thus requires little memory.

Comment: My goodness, you're absolutely right, @Peter. I'd been running into a PHP memory limit problem earlier and I was so blinkered that I didn't even register that I was looking at a completely different error ‍♀️ Your solution has worked like magic, so after hours of headache-inducing-frustration and running in circles, we have it working!

Comment: you are bravo. you saved me from big headache. i wasted lot of time to resolve memory issue.